# How to load images into RAM for later use in .kv file (Kivy+Python)

Tags: python, image, kivy

**Question:**

I need to find a way to preload my .png files, because at some points of my code, graphics that should be buttons appear as black squares while at other points (exactly same code) they work perfectly.
I thougt of doing that in a python class at startup, and attach them later in my .kv files.
The crux is, that I use `source:` and "preloading" a string like `'assets/graphics/buttons/newImg.png'`would store the string, not the image. And if I load the image another way, I don't know how to attach that later to my buttons.

Any hints and/or ideas are appreciated!

**Background:**

I created my buttons like this:

```
<MyButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>
    widgetTarget: ''
    source: 'assets/graphics/buttons/' + self.widgetTarget + '.png'
    on_press:
        self.source = 'assets/graphics/buttons/' + self.widgetTarget + '_clicked.png'
    on_release:
        self.source = 'assets/graphics/buttons/' + self.widgetTarget + '.png'
```

and use it like that in my .kv files:

```
CustomButtonNoTarget:
        id: meIsButton
        widgetTarget: 'stopSign'
        on_release:
           *do stuff here*
```

Most of the time, that works like a charm, but at certain points in the program flow, instead of images only black squares (same size) appear.

Because the exact same code worked at other positions in program flow I focused on the images:
I tested:
different images - different image types - different image sizes

-> all results exactly the same.

Then I stumbled over a hint: If I used the same graphic BEFORE the problematic position, it's loaded perfectly later on. So I think the problem is that - why so ever that happens at just few positions and not all the time - the image can't be loaded fast enought. Because RAM is faster it works, when the image allready is in RAM.

So my idea to solve that would be to store all images in memory at startup, what leads me to obove asked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could load all the images up front, put them in a corner, invisible, before the rest of your code runs?

Comment: So creating them once on startup in the background?
I thougt of that too, but it feels kind of badly coded, to just let them go after that and not use it in any way. :/

Comment: Agreed, but if there's some issue with what you're trying to do that means it's necessary, then I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: True that. I'll try that, but I'd like to see a more nicely coded solution, if there is one and someone can give a hint.
What I thought about is, if there is an option including the data parameter of the image class. Perhaps in combination with the keep_data parameter also from the Image Class API.
The problem is I can't find any examples that use them so that I can see how to work with them.

Comment: I'm guessing you've read https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html page on asynchronous image loading, right?

Comment: Yes of course ;)
But the problem seems not to be that loading the image blocks the App, but the other way around: The App loads the site to fast so the image can't be loaded.
At least it feels like that. And the test I did seem to proof that.
I tried it anyway a few moments ago but AsyncImage seems not to solve the problem. The button stays black.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. I edited your answer to show what I did exactly. Even if I absolutely don't like the way it solved that problem and feels terribly wrong, I have to admit: It works! So you should get the reputation for it (if there's some in for you). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Think I shouldn't have count my chickens... The bug is not gone. It looked like that but on the second glance it seems like it's sporadic now. About 80% of time it's still the black square. :(

Comment: All I can suggest is that you post *all* the code so folks can see if there's a typo you missed, or some error in principle...

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this issue as I try to add **gif** image onto `ModalView` in the code.

The solution I found is to use `AsyncImage` and set the **color** to `transparent (1,1,1,0)`, **nocache** to *True*, and later set the color back by binding `on_load`. This works very well in my situation.